# Where are Sessions are being started?

Tags: php, theme-twenty-eleven, plugin-wp-e-commerce, session

I have this site here http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/, I am using twentyeleven theme and there is a session I need to adjust called 'PHPSESSID'

The problem I having with PHPSESSID is that when you goto my site you will see nothing in the top right corner, you refresh the a shopping cart appears, when I delete PHPSESSID it goes away again. I'm using wp e-commerce plugin

Comment: I disable my plugins and the session came from wp-ecommerce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into wp-ecommerce/wpsc-includes/shopping_cart_functions.php and adjusting this line

```
if ( isset( $cart ) ) {
echo wpsc_shopping_basket_internals( $cart, false, true );
}
```

to this

```
//if ( isset( $cart ) ) {
echo wpsc_shopping_basket_internals( $cart, false, true );
//}
```